# Inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $u_t=u_{xx}+cu_x+au, a,c\in\mathbb{R}$ with Inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

Determine the equilibrium State and the spectrum.

(1) What is meant with Inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions Here?

Does this mean we are searching for some Solution u on some interval (a,b) with $u(a)=\alpha, u(b)=\beta$?

(2) Isn't the equilibrium State simply u=0?

I guess the spectrum is given By

$\lambda= -k^2+ikc +a$

and with the Ansatz $u(t,x)=e^{ikx}$ and the boundary condition is it possible to determine k?

Comment: (1): yes apparently that is what it means - never heard that before myself, so had to check.
(2): I would think that equalibrium state is when $u_t=0$ - leaving you with a rather easy second order ODE.

Comment: Then the equilibria depend on whether $c^2/4$ is either equal to, less than or larger or equal to a.